# Missing test results in build summary

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, testing

I've got a Vs2008 solution being build on TFS2010 and for some reason the test results are not present in the build summary. We use the upgrade template with not customizations. Test results are not present vs2008 and vs2010. Any thoughts?

Additional Info: We use MSBuild 3.5 - Not quite sure what the consequences would be if I upgraded to 4.0.

[image: Screen shot of build summary from vs2008 and vs2010]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so changing the msbuild version from 3.5 to 4.0 did the trick.

Comment: How did you change the MS build version for the build definition?

Comment: Left TFS long time ago :). If my memory serves me right, it's in the template configuration.